# PHP paging loop no visible link

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

Good evening,I'm trying to create a paging system to display a certain amount of data per page. Everything works fine except a little detail : no visible link.

To be a little more precise : My user has 9 articles on his personnal page. Considering I want to have 4 articles per page, I should have 3 pages in total (the last one with only 1 article).
My links look like this :  http://127.0.0.1/projet3/mesannonces.php?page=1

When manually changing the page in the URL (page=2 ..) the page shows exactly what should be displayed. So, I tried to create a loop to display links instead of using the URL

```
     <?php  
     for($i=1;$i<=$pagesTotales;$i++)
     { echo '<a href="mesannonces.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>' ; }
```

This loop should show 3 clikable links, however, it only shows 1. I wonder what I may be doing wrong considering that manually setting the URL to the next page shows the correct page.

Everything works fine except that only the first page's link is visible when it should show exactly 3

Should you find this helpful, here is the entire page code, after trimming unecessary codes :

```
<?php
session_start();

$mesannonces=$_SESSION['id'];

//tentative de connexion à la base de donnée 
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=espace_membre;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage()); //message d'erreur au cas où la connexion échoue
}

////////////////////////////////////PAGING SYSTEM/////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($_GET['page']) AND !empty($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page']>0)
{
  $_GET['page']=intval($_GET['page']); //pour qu'on ne puisse pas passer autre chose que des chiffres dans l'URL 
  $pageCourante=$_GET['page'];
}
else
{
  $pageCourante=1; // si l'URL est incomplète, on est redirigé vers la première page 
}


$articleParPage=5; // choisir le nombre d'annonce d'articles par page 
$depart=($pageCourante-1)*$articleParPage ;

 $articleTotalSQL=$bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE fk_membres_id= ? ORDER BY date_publication DESC LIMIT '.$depart.','.$articleParPage.' ');
 $articleTotalSQL->execute(array($mesannonces));
$articleTotal=$articleTotalSQL->rowCount();
$pagesTotales=ceil($articleTotal/$articleParPage);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{   echo "ok"; 

}
else
{
  //echo "lol";
  header('location:connexion.php');
} 
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Profil de <?php echo $_SESSION['pseudo']?></title>    
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>


<body>
   <div align="center">
         <h3>Tes annonces TROKI</h3>
        <br/>
         <?php 
            if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
            {
             ?>
            <h3>les annonces de <?php echo $_SESSION['pseudo']?> </h3>
          pseudo = <?php echo $_SESSION['pseudo']?> <br/>
            
             <?php 
            }
           ?>
  </div>
 <div align="center">
   <ul>
    <?php while($a=$articleTotalSQL->fetch()) { ?>
  
    <!-- this loop shows the articles from the database, everything works fine here-->
    <li>
       <img src="miniature/<?=$a['id']?>.jpg" width=50> <!-- la miniature de l'annonce-->
      <a href="annonce.php?id=<?= $a['id']?>"><?=$a['titre_article']?> <?php echo $a['wilaya']?> <?php echo $a['type_article']?> </a> <a href="modifierannonce.php?edit=<?= $a['id']?> ">     modifier une annonce </a><a href="supprimerannonce.php?=<?= $a['id']?>">      supprimer</a></li>




    <?php } ?>  
   </ul>
 </div>
   <!-- pour changer de page-->
   <div align="center"> 
          <?php  
     for($i=1;$i<=$pagesTotales;$i++) //this loop only shows 1 link instead of 3 
     { 
       echo '<a href="mesannonces.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>' ; 
     }
?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. Pagination is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your page total calculation is wrong. You're computing based on the number of rows *fetched*, not the number of rows that matched before the `LIMIT` was applied. If you `LIMIT 5`, then the number of rows fetched will always be less than or equal to 5, regardless of how many rows are in the table.

If you need to know the total number of matches you have to do a secondary calculation with a `COUNT(*)` and the same `WHERE` constraints.

Comment: That's not quite exactly what I'm trying to do. From my perspective and my basic needs, everything works fine. I just do not understand why the loop doesn't show the links to go to page 2 and 3 when I'am still able to access them when manually changing the page's value in the URL
http://127.0.0.1/projet3/mesannonces.php?page=2
http://127.0.0.1/projet3/mesannonces.php?page=3

Comment: Normally you'd show links like `< 1 2 3 ... 5 6 7 >`, and to do that you need to know the *total count*, something you cannot obtain unless you explicitly ask for it. Read again my remark about the `COUNT(*)` part.